# How to Use OpenSSL project in my Windows C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, openssl

I have query related to how to use OpenSSL project in my C++ application.

I saw there was one installer that was registering the library  and then we have to use this library in our application.

But actually I have my own project where I want to use  openssl .c and .h files without using dll.

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I build OpenSSL statically linked against Windows runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486243/how-do-i-build-openssl-statically-linked-against-windows-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

Normally using DLLs is a good idea because it will enable others (that don't have your sourcecode) to update the openssl version in use by your program.
When we consider the plethora of security issues from the last months this is a good thing ...

If you still want to statically include the openssl code into your program you can do so by including the files into your project and calling them directly.

See stackoverflow for examples, this might be one that fits your scenario: [How do I build OpenSSL statically linked against Windows runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486243/how-do-i-build-openssl-statically-linked-against-windows-runtime?rq=1)