# How to build openssl 1.1.1 dlls for VC-WIN32 without dependency on vcruntime-dlls (/MT)

Tags: openssl

I want to compile openSSL 1.1.1c as DLLs without dependency on the visual C runtimes. For openSSL 1.0.2 it was enough to patch the ntdll.mak (after configuring) replacing /MD with /MT.

For openSSL 1.1.1c many tests (from several categories) fail when I change /MD to /MT in the makefile and the configdata.pm after `perl configure VC-WIN32`. Without patching the files both compile and test are OK.
Using the no-shared in configure is no option either as it doesn't create the DLLs.

Maybe I'm just missing a configure option?

In case it matters: I'm using Strawberry Perl 5.28.0.1 Portable, NASM 2.14.02 and MS VC2017 Enterprise.

P.S. I'm aware of the binaries linked from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494745/2131459  but at least the OpenSSL 1.1.1 versions of "32-Bit Release Static Library" appear to also depend on vcruntime140.dll (according to depends.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing I have downloaded libssl and libcrypto dlls from a website just for check them in the dependency walker. When I checked it I realized it couldn't find any dependency to the vcruntime140.dll. I am wondering how he could manage to do that. I am still trying to build openssl without dependency.
If you want to check it out you can find them in here http://p-nand-q.com/programming/windows/building_openssl_with_visual_studio_2013.html