# Using OpenSSL in C project on windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, openssl, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm using Windows and I wonder how can I install/compile OpenSSL (Version 1.1.1) as a static library that will be included in my C project (the aim here is to avoid installing OpenSSL on every computer that will run my code).

I saw few  questions about that, but they all use Visual Studio. I rather want to use VS Code so i can understand everything that is done. And because I prefer coding in VS Code.

Other topic realted to my question:

- [How do I build OpenSSL statically linked against Windows runtime ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486243/how-do-i-build-openssl-statically-linked-against-windows-runtime?rq=1)
- [Difference between shared objects (.so), static libraries (.a), and DLL's (.so)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200/difference-between-shared-objects-so-static-libraries-a-and-dlls-so)

I'm a bit new to C shared object, static library and DLL. As I understand the difference between **.so** and **.a**, is that a **.a** file will be included in the **.exe** after compilation so that people don't have to install OpenSSL for using my program.